# Masking a list against a string in Python

Tags: python

I have the following:

```
  str1 ='-CGCG-G'
  ls1 = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
  # length of ls and str always the same
  # and the value of ls1 can be anything. It is not the index of str1
```

What I want to do is to mask the list `l1` based on `str1`,
by keeping the member of list where the corresponding position is not `-` in string. 
Yielding

```
output = [1,2,3,4,6]
```

How can I achieve that conveniently in Python?
I looked at [itertools.compress](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress), but I can't think of a way
to use it for my purpose.

Comment: why do you need `ls1`? Will the value of `ls1` be different from 0, 1, 2, ...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `zip` to combine the two, then use a list comprehension to filter whenever the character in the string is `-`:

```
output = [num for char, num in zip(str1, ls1) if char != '-']
```

The `zip` function will take two lists, and 'combine' them together. In this case, doing `zip(str1, ls1)` will produce:

```
[('-', 0), ('C', 1), ('G', 2), ('C', 3), ('G', 4), ('-', 5), ('G', 6)]
```

From there, it's relatively straightforward to iterate through that list and filter out all the pairs where the character is a dash.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using [`itertools.compress`](http://itertools.compress) as well.

```
>>> from itertools import compress
>>> ls1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> str1 = '-CGCG-G'
>>> f = compress(ls1, [0 if j == '-' else 1 for j in list(str1)])    # compress([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1])
>>> filtered = [i for i in f]
>>> filtered
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
>>> str1 ='-CGCG-G'
>>> ls1 = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> [a for idx, a in enumerate(a) if str1[idx] != '-']
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
```

Comment: If you're using `enumerate()` like this you probably don't need `ls1` in the first place.

Comment: @Marius I corrected my mistake of interchanging the variables `idx` and `a`

Comment: I was thinking more like `[idx for idx, a in enumerate(str1) if a != '-']`

Comment: note that the value of `ls1` can be anything. It is not the index of `str1`.

Comment: @Marius That would work only if `ls1` were 0 indexed numbers as in the current example.

Comment: @shaktimaan Yes, my suggestion only works if the values in `ls1` were just indices for `str1`, which is apparently not the case. You should check your current answer though, because I don't think it works?